# Issue with python httplib2 on linux

Tags: python, linux, httplib2

I'm using the following snippet of code to call a web service, that requires basic auth:

```
import urllib
import httplib2
url='http://heywatch.com/download.json'
body={'username':'my_username','password':'my_password'}
header_data={'Accept': 'application/json'}
http=httplib2.Http()
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=header_data,     body=urllib.urlencode(body))
```

I'm running this same snippet on two different environments:

Mac OSX 10.6.6, python version 2.6.1 - I get the correct response

Linux - centos, python version 2.6.6 - I get the following exception:

```
.....
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1129, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at heywatch.com
```

I've run this code on multiple linux flavors with different python versions and everything works fine.  I also noticed curl does not work properly on the particular machine.  The following curl command (which mimics the code above) works fine on my Mac OSX:

```
curl -u username:password -X POST -d "url=https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_video_to_be_encoded.mov" -d "title=new_video" -d "automatic_encode=true" -d "ping_url_after_encode=http://mydomain/video_encode_success" https://heywatch.com/download.json
```

but fails on the affected linux workstation with the following message:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'heywatch.com'
```

Any idea why this is happening?  It seems like some OS setting is incorrect.  If it helps, I'm using an [amazon version of linux](http://aws.amazon.com/amis/4157) in amazon ec2, which is fairly locked down.

Comment: this will not be an issue with Python, but with the underlying setup of the box you are on. What happens if you run 'dig heywatch.com' ?

Comment: Definately not a issue with python or the target services I want to use.  Here is the response from the _dig heywatch.com_:              ; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P2-RedHat-9.7.0-5.P2.8.amzn1 <<>> heywatch.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23746
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;heywatch.com.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
heywatch.com.  25945 IN A 91.121.11.87

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.0.23#53(172.16.0.23)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul  6 15:52:38 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how the linux box is resolving heywatch.com. CAn you do a ping to see if heywatch.com is reachable (probably not). You might want to look at /etc/resolv.conf on your linux box to see what nameservers are configured and ask amazon if you are using any of theirs.

FWIW, I just tried to resolve heywatch on my ubuntu in linode and it seems to resolve fine.

Comment: For the time being I commented out the search entry in the resolv.conf file and curl now works. Not sure why or what the consequences are (I'll have to do some research).  Thanks!

Comment: **Update**  The curl command works after editing my /etc/resolve.conf.  My original code still fails.  I now see the following exception:  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 911, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:490: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: If you have a self-signed certificate (which is what you seem to have), then you have to make python understand that its fine to use that. What kind of a protocol do you use to connect to that site.. This is exactly what you see when you view https://heywatch.com/page/home , you would see that the browser will indicate its an self-signed certificate and is not able to verify its validity.

Comment: Try running it using http to ensure that the communication works.